# Cannot retrieve license from Marmalade SDK server

Tags: marmalade

I have evaluation license, but cannot retrieve it. Of course connection is working, firewall disabled and etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've managed to retrieve license with help of Marmalade support.

What I've done:

- previously I've retrieved it on virtual machine

1) wrote to support

2) ?they've made something with my license (I don't know)?

3) released license in my account

4) reinstalled Marmalade SDK

5) retrieved license

Answer (score 0):

Check Proxy settings in Internet explorer. Marmalade take the proxy settings automatically from IE. Whenever I have this issue on a new machine, I disable the Auto proxy setting to manual in IE and it works.

Comment: It doesn't help in my case

Comment: Did you try reinstalling marmalade?